# System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred error in asp.net core angular app with Visual studio 2017

Tags: angular, asp.net-core

I am using visual studio 2017 and generated Asp.net core +Angular application. When I try to publish the application. I received below error:

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.ThrowIfExceptional(Boolean includeTaskCanceledExceptions)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Wait(Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.PublishService.VsWebProjectPublish.<>c__DisplayClass43_0.<PublishAsync>b__2()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task`1.InnerInvoke()
   at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.Execute()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.ApplicationCapabilities.Publish.ViewModel.ProfileSelectorViewModel.<RunPublishTaskAsync>d__127.MoveNext()
---> (Inner Exception #0) System.Exception: Build failed. Check the Output window for more details.<---
===================
```

Can anyone let me know the way to solve this issue?

Comment: `Build failed. Check the Output window for more details` Any useful info for troubleshooting the issue in Output window?

Comment: Did you try cleaning the solution, restoring nuget packages, rebuilding first (before straight publishing..i know its the same effect but just in case) and seeing that the application works then? How about docker config? Is that enabled? Is https disabled? Is this solution straight out of the box you're trying to publish or you made changes to it?